# ASP.NET MVC Search Box on Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created the search form and results from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application which handles paging and sorting using the PagedList Nuget package.

What I need help with though, is how do I put the search form on my master page?  (_layout.cshtml)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put a from contains a Text box and a button and the form's action will be the search action

Ex code in the `_layout.cshtml` page

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Query)

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, got it working, but had to change FormMethod.Get to FormMethod.Post.  Also, how do I clear the entry in the text box when showing the results?

Comment: you should use `GET` because it means the request coming to the server will not change any data , but `POST` does, about clearing the field , in the form's posted action make the Query property that you pass to the view equal empty string

Comment: But if I use GET then I don't get any search results back... EDIT I fixed that, it was because the code specifically looked for a GET and set the search to nothing.  Thanks again.

Comment: post example code for your controller action that you post to , your model and your view form , but i can say the `Http` verbs (`GET`, `POST`) are irrelevant to the data and your application logic